# increasing a number inside of a mouseClicked funtion

Tags: javascript

I have a code where I draw an object when the mouse is clicked using `mouseClicked = function(){}` and then I need to have a number to show how many objects have been drawn. the problem is that the number won't increase. what do I do?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Hey Anna and welcome to SO. To really understand your question it is implied that you include your code which you refer to into a code block, snippet or (but less preferably) a fiddle/bin/pen. Check out [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the help section for more information. This will increase the chance of getting quality help with your question.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than declaring and incrementing a global variable - you could set the count as a HTML 5 data attribute on the button and then on clicking the button, get the data attribute value, increment it and update the display and the new count on the button.

Note that data-attributes are always strings - hence the need for the parseInt() method, though if I was being a purist - I would have put the radix in as well, but that defaults to 10 - so no need in this case.

It is always better to avoid global variable when possible and data attributes offer a very conveniant way of storing local data.

Thanks to @Sven.hig for the skeletn code of the solution - which I then modified to my approach.

```js
var res=document.getElementById("res")
var btn=document.getElementById("btn")

btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  const newCount = parseInt(btn.getAttribute('data-count'))+1;
  res.textContent = newCount;
  btn.setAttribute('data-count', newCount)
})
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>

<button id="btn" data-count="0">Draw</button>
```

Comment: You can replace `parseInt` with `+`.

Comment: Thanks @GirkovArpa - would rather do it with parseInt() than type coersion from string to number. But good to know - cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that will give you an idea about how to increment a counter

```js
var res=document.getElementById("res")
var btn=document.getElementById("btn")
var count=1
btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    res.textContent=count
    count++
    
})
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>

<button id="btn">Draw</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the count variable is defined inside the mouseClicked function as the title say, you are recreating it in every mouseClick. In this case, you should define it outter the function with value = 0 and, inside the function, sum 1 to that value. Anyway, like the comments say, it's necessary that you include the code to your question to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is an easy way to counter the clicks on a html document.

```js
let counter = 0;    

document.onclick = () => {
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);
}
```